# how can a method return a Set in java?

Tags: java, set, return

I am calling a method from an api that returns a Set Object. As far as I know, a Set is an interface, and you cannot instantiate an interface. I am able to take this set and call toArray() on it. what is Set actually returning then?

Comment: The method will return an instance of some class that implements the `Set` interface. See [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does return a `Set`, but you must understand, that a `Set` is more than just the interface:

Every implementation of every class that implements `Set` can be returned.

```
public Set getMySet(){
  return new HashSet();
}
```

since `HashSet` implements `Set`, this is valid code that will work.

Writing applications to interfaces rather than their implementations is a widely used practice. After all, all you need to write (and test) your code (for instance the UI using a service), is the interface.

You can't get the concrete implementations yet, they may not even exist yet, but you can already do all the work you need to do.

Comment: so the developer who created the method designed it to return some object that implemented the Set interface. Since the method returns a Set, do I have the option to select which object I want that Set to be? Such as the developer may return a HashSet object, but Can I say TreeSet ts = methodThatReturnsSet() ?

Comment: @brentryczak No. You can convert the received set to a different type if you need to, but the method return type is telling you "I will return something that implements `Set`, and you shouldn't need to know what implementation it happens to be."

Comment: so my options are to call a method right from the return statement that the interface contains (ie methodThatReturnsSet().someMethod(), or to cast it to a class that implements it (ie TreeSet ts = (TreeSet) methodThatReturnsSet()).

Comment: @brentryczak if you are the one writing the setter, yes. Otherwise, you shouldn't care. You'll be able to perform all the tasks a Set can do, and no other. No matter which implementation is returned, whether it provides additional features or not, they won't be available in your code, since all your code knows it's a Set. When someone writes code like that, they want you to work with a(ny) Set, not with a specific type.

Answer (score 1):

Returning an interface from a method means that the returned object will implement that interface.

In this case it means that the object returned will implement 'Set'. You will be able to call methods which are contained in that interface but will not be able to call methods from the implementing class.